# Está dando erro ImportError at /post/new/ No module named 'blog.forms'

Tags: python, django, syntax-error

Nesta linha: C:\Users\Fer Gomes\djangogirls\mysite\blog\views.py in , line 5
o codigo

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .forms import PostForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Fernanda, você pode dar mais detalhes na sua pergunta? Como por exemplo a estrutura de diretórios do seu projeto?

Comment: Tengo el mismo error, y seguí al pie de la letra este tutorial: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/es/django_forms/